# Varios Banco de dados acessados ao mesmo tempo JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hoje eu tenho o seguinte cenário: meus clientes entram no meu site e aparece a tela de login, onde peço o Grupo do usuário, o Login e Senha.

Para o Grupo eu tenho um banco de dados, onde tem os dados do banco de dados dos usuário ou seja, em qual servidor ele esta alocado o nome etc.

Com isso, eu verifico se o grupo existe. Se ele existe eu fecho a conexão do meu Banco de dados do Grupo, que se chama Gestor, e abro a conexão do banco de dados do usuário.

Cada usuario tem seu banco de dados, entao eu abro a conexao do banco de dados do usuario depois de verificado se existe o grupo e gravo em um `HTTPSESSION` (obs : Gravo o  `EntityManegerFactory` na sessao), assim toda vez q ele for fazer uma pesquisa, eu faco o `EntityManager` receber esse *factory* da sessao.

Quero saber se isso pode deixar o sistema lento, pois o meu servidor do java está travando, queria saber se é por esse motivo.

Aqui eu gravo o o banco de dados do cliente na sessao:

```
 public EntityManager getEntityManager(String PU, String Local, String endfdb) {

    if (PU.equals("0")) {
        GestorEMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("GestorPU");
        return GestorEMF.createEntityManager();
    } else {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:firebirdsql:"+endfdb+"/3050:" + Local);

        usrEMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PU, props);
        HttpSession sess = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        sess.setAttribute("mitryusEMF", mitryusEMF);
        return mitryusEMF.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Aqui eu seto o EM toda vez q o usuario precisa:

```
 public EntityManager getEntityMitryus() {
    EntityManagerFactory usuario = (EntityManagerFactory) getSession().getAttribute("mitryusEMF");

    return usuario.createEntityManager();
}
```

Comment: Você não disse qual banco usa, mas eu já implementei um sistema parecido com PostgreSQL usando apenas um `EntityManagerFactory`, porém variando o `schema`. Dentro de uma requisição do usuário, cada vez que uma conexão vai ser feita, eu verifico qual é o `schema` adequado para atender ao usuário, dependendo de uma série de regras de negócio, e modifico a nova conexão (ou retirada do pool) definindo o `schema` selecionado.

Comment: Infelizmente o `EMF` é caro para criar e manter na sessão não me parece algo muito legal, pois isso significa manter um por usuário (isso se o usuário usar uma só sessão), o que é desnecessário e vai diminuir a escalabilidade do sistema. Outra ideia seria manter um `EMF` por banco num "pool" mantido por você. Se você usa Spring Framework não deve ser difícil criar um facotry para isso. Enfim, são só considerações, pois às vezes é melhor repensar o que estamos usando do que ficar tentando resolver problemas mais complicados.

Comment: Amigo me arrumo um ex sobre isso